# Questions & explanation verifications about Stein and Shakarchi complex analysis chapter 8 proposition 1.1

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I'm an undergrad taking my first complex analysis course, and I ran into something I wasn't completely clear about in Stein & Shakarchi's complex analysis book right at the beginning of the section on conformal mappings.

> If $f: U \rightarrow V$ is holomorphic and injective, then $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in U$. In particular, the inverse of $f$ defined on its range is holomorphic, and thus the inverse of a conformal map is also holomorphic.

The proof starts by supposing $f'(z_0) = 0$ for some $z_0 \in U$, and then says that

> f(z) - f(z_0) = a(z-z_0)^k + G(z)

Where $k \geq 2$, and $G(z)$ vanishes of order $k+1$ near $z_0$. The authors don't really explain why this is true, but my best guess is that they're just taking the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $z_0$. **Is that accurate?**

Next, they say that for sufficiently small circle around $z_0$, and for sufficiently small $w$, we have the following two properties:

1] $|G(z)| < |a(z-z_0)^k - w|$ on the circle

2] $|a(z-z_0)^k - w|$ has at least two zeros inside the circle

Neither of these is explained either. **But I'm wondering if the following is a valid explanation**: because $G(z)$ vanishes of order greater than $k$, there is some circle $C$ around $z_0$ such that on $C$, $|G(z)| < |a(z-z_0)^k|$, so choosing $|w| < |a(z-z_0)^k| - |G(z)|$, we have $|a(z-z_0)^k - w| \geq |a(z-z_0)^k| - |w| > G(z)$. Also, because $|G(z)| > 0$, we also have $|w| < |a(z-z_0)^k|$ so by Rouche's theorem, $|a(z-z_0)^k - w|$ still has at least two zeros inside the circle.

Therefore, by Rouche's theorem, $f(z) - f(z_0) - w$ also has two zeros inside the circle.

So far, if my above explanations are correct, I'm not really running into trouble. However, now the authors assert

> Since $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ for all $z \neq z_0$ in a small circle around $z_0$, the roots of $f(z) - f(z_0) - w$ must be distinct.

Here for some reason I don't follow at all why this is true, my brain just can't seem to pick up the connection. **Would someone mind explaining why the roots have to be distinct?**

Later on, Stein and Shakarchi say that if $f$ is bijective and holomorphic, and $g$ is its inverse, we have

$$\frac{g(w) - g(w_0)}{w-w_0} = \frac{1}{\frac{w-w_0}{g(w) - g(w_0)}} = \frac{1}{\frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0}}$$

And then they let $z \rightarrow z_0$ to get the derivative of $g$. But my question is, when we calculate the derivative of $g$, shouldn't we instead let $w \rightarrow w_0$? If we say that this is the same as letting $g(w) \rightarrow g(w_0)$, **doesn't that require g to be continuous?** How do we know continuity of $g$ from holomorphicity of $f$?

Would anyone mind verifying that my earlier explanations make sense, and also explaining my latter two questions? Edit: I bolded my questions to separate them from the rest of the proof. Thanks!